# How to set AttributeSet in a function

Tags: android

I have the following code..

```
public LabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initLabelView();
```

how can i set the value of AtributeSet and pass it the constructor from other activity..

Comment: I think it would be better if you tried to explain the general idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you use AttributeSet directly then you will need to manually check for resource references (with getAttributeResourceValue(int,int)) and do the resource lookup yourself if needed. Direct use of AttributeSet also prevents the application of themes and styles when retrieving attribute values.

Rather than trying to modify the AttributeSet in the constructor. Your best bet is to simply override the values of attributes I want to change. This might also require overriding or re-implementing protected/public methods from the parent (LabelView or View) that use that attribute.